# Image not responsive and overflows container in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, image, responsive

**Scenario :**

- I have a bloglist in Wordpress in which I have post items, which consist out of an image (thumbnail, full) and other content.
- Somehow, the thumbnail image is not acting responsive and I have no idea why. - Because it is not responsive, it also overflows the container. I know how to fix that offcourse, but still the image is not responsive then.
- If I manually set the max-width, I still have incorrect aspect ratio.
  It should simply be scaled by the browser in it's container.

[This is the relevant page:](https://www.comparexperts.nl/verzekering-nieuws/)

I have tried many solutions that were given in similar questions, but none of these have helped out. I hope someone can :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the `Global.css` file and the `.page-template-bloglist .wp-post-month` class.

code :

```
width: 100%;
```

Comment: hi there, thanks Behnam. I noticed indeed that my theme was missing a responsive sort of class, width already did that, but also needed height: auto